# Dynamically created element and functions used with onblur not running properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, parameters

i am trying to pass some parameters to a function with "onBlur" event as following:

```
var str = "<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td colspan='8'>";
            str += "<input onBlur='blurEdit("+sno+","+field+");' value='"+$.trim($('#'+elementId).text())+"' type='text' class='form-control' name='edit_"+field+"' id='edit_"+field+"'>"+
                    "<span id='msgEdit'></span></td></tr>";
            $(str).insertAfter($("#"+rowId));
```

But the function `onBlur=blurEdit("+sno+",'"+field+"')` is not going to accept the second parameter value and its because it is enclosed with a string value.
How to use a function inside a javascript created string?

Comment: can you post a jsfiddle or a code pen for your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used same statement `onBlur=blurEdit("+sno+",'"+field+"');` seems working for me. Make sure you are not giving any `'` before and after`blurEdit` as you have given it in your question.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btn1").click(function(){
var field ="name";
var sno=1;
var str="<input onBlur=blurEdit("+sno+",'"+field+"'); type='text'/>";
$(str).insertAfter($("#rowId"));
});
});
var  blurEdit = function(sno,field){
alert(field);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="rowId"></div>
<button id="btn1">Append Text</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a separate variable

```
var fun="blurEdit("+sno+","+field+");";
```

and then in the string

```
var str = "<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td colspan='8'>";
 str += "<input onBlur='"+fun+"' value='"+$.trim($('#'+elementId).text())+"' type='text' class='form-control' name='edit_"+field+"' id='edit_"+field+"'>"+
                "<span id='msgEdit'></span></td></tr>";
        $(str).insertAfter($("#"+rowId));
```

Try out this .It should work for you

Comment: i want to get values of string params as it takes in the function parameter list

Comment: function blurEdit(sno,field){console.log(sno+"+++++"+field)}. is this not working ?

Comment: in fact the +field+ create problem, its says that "testingText" is not defined? where "testingText" is the value in param +field+?

Comment: Have you tried my code?.The problem is just because of the quotes('' and "").Use it properly and everything will work fine.

Comment: Yes that is the problem, I have tried your code too, but there is no accepted result...